# Meta box: Undefined index

Tags: plugins

I have custom meta box which uses the WordPress media uploader tool to add a picture to custom post type called slides. Below is the code I have used.

```
<?php
// Custom meta boxes - Image upload

// Declare meta box
function add_upload_file_metaboxes()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'slide_image_upload', //ID
        'Image', //Title of meta box
        'slide_file_upload', // Callback function
        'slides', //Post type
        'normal', // Location
        'high' // Priority
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_upload_file_metaboxes' );
?>
<?php
// Enqueue scripts for media uploader
function admin_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
}
function admin_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_styles');
?>
<?php
// Force insert into post button
add_filter('get_media_item_args', 'allow_img_insertion');
function allow_img_insertion($vars) {
    $vars['send'] = true;
    return($vars);
}

// Render the meta box
function slide_file_upload()
{
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    $strFile = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key = 'slide_image', $single = true );
?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function()
            {
                formfield = jQuery(this).prev().attr('name');
                inp_id = jQuery(this).prev().attr('id');
                jQuery('#img_txt_id').val(inp_id);
                tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id=<?php  echo $post->ID; ?>&type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
            return false;
            }
        );

        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
            img_cont = jQuery('#img_txt_id').val();
            //console.log(html);
            var imgurl =jQuery(html).attr("href");
            jQuery('#'+img_cont).val(imgurl);
            tb_remove();
        };
    } ) ;
</script>
<p>
    <label for="slide_image">Image:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="slide_image" id="slide_image" size="80%" style="height:30px; float:right;" value="<?php echo $strFile; ?>" />
    <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload" class="button button-primary button-large" style="width:20%;">
    <br><br>
    <p>Preview:</p>
    <img src="<?php echo $strFile; ?>" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="img_txt_id" id="img_txt_id" value="" />
<?php
}
// Save the data
function save_slides_meta($post_id, $post)
{    
    // Check users permissions
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
    return $post->ID;

    // Source the data
    $slides_meta['slide_image'] = $_POST['slide_image'];

    // Save the data
    foreach ($slides_meta as $key => $value)
    {
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return;
            $value = implode(',', (array)$value);
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE))
        {
            // If the custom field already has a value it will update
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the custom field doesn't have a value it will add
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        // Delete if blank value
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_slides_meta', 1, 2);
?>
```

However it does through up an  error message throughout the site...

**Notice: Undefined index: slide_image in .../custom-post-types.php on line 223**

This message appears three times and they each refer to the following item:

```
$slides_meta['slide_image'] = $_POST['slide_image'];
```

I have tried a number of methods to resolve this but with no joy. The function of the plugin works perfectly and the images upload to the post but this message prevails across the site. Can anyone help enlighten me as to the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you try to wrap it into a if(isset($_POST['slide_image']) && !empty($_POST['slide_image'])) {...} or something? Just to see...

Comment: Hi @Djouuuuh, I changed it and wrapped the foreach within it but now received two new error messages when posting...

'Undefined variable: slides_meta...'
and
'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...'

Although I received no error messages throughout the admin area.